# C# compiler not found when building a package (Monodevelop - linux)

Tags: monodevelop

I'm trying mono develop on linux, but trying to create a package, gives me the error Could not obtain a C# compiler. C# compiler not found for Mono / .NET 3.5.

I assumed the compiler was installed with monodevelop. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can switch to the now default 4.0 runtime in :

`project -> project-name options -> build -> general -> runtime version`

Or if you don't have the compiler installed at all use :

`sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs`

to install it.

Comment: Actually, haven't found it in any of the mono tutorials :)